# how to use parameter in linq to select different columns

Tags: c#, linq

i want to use linq to select certain columns to populate each combobox.
 right i have individual linq query to do the job. i wish to write a method to do that.

```
var getUserName = Entity.Select(a=>a.Username);
var getType  = Entity.Select(a=>a.Type);
var getAddress  = Entity.Select(a=>a.Address);
```

can i do something like that:

```
   Public object GetData(string columnName) {  
 var q = from a in Entity
              Select columnName;
 return q.distinct();

    }

combobox1.bindingsource = GetData("Username");
combobox2.bindingsource = GetData("Type");
combobox3.bindingsource = GetData("Address");
```

do i need to write a construct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic LINQ will be helpful in this situation.
Here is a [tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).
The code you need will look like this:

```
    public object GetData (string colName) {
      NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext();
      var q = db.Products.Select(colName);
      List list = new List();
      foreach (var element in q) {
        if (!list.Contains(element))
          list.Add(element);
      }
      return list;
```